# Virtual LANs in memory for several virtual machines on one host

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vlan, lan

Suppose I have host machine with no NIC.

I would like to run several virtual machines on it and connect them with totally virtual LANs in between. I want many machines and many LANs.

I would like to experiment with network configs this way.

What tools allow me to do this?

Comment: If you don't need different OS on the virtual machines, and just want to experiment with networks, google "network namespaces". Use veth-pairs to built as complicated LANs as you want.

Comment: The are also tools like [Core](https://downloads.pf.itd.nrl.navy.mil/docs/core/core-html/intro.html#how-does-it-work) which allow you to configure your network in a GUI, if you prefer that.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, unless you need actual isolation of groups of machines, you shouldn't need to do anything special.  The standard approach of using a bridge interface to connect virtual machines to the host network works just fine in most cases even without needing actual networking hardware on the host.  In fact, the bridge interface in this standard setup exists solely so that the virtual machine manager has something to connect the virtual network interfaces for the virtual machines to, because it's kind of hard to directly expose a VM to the network without some kind of intermediary layer.

As a more concrete example, here's an excerpt from the output of `ip link show` on one of my systems where I run a bunch of virtual machines:

```
6: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:20:b5:bd:42:4b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast aster br0 state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:98:c5:54:95:2a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: tap1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast aster br0 state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:97:56:bf:0c:81 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

On this system, the software bridge interface `br0` serves as a network segment that all the VM's connect to, providing functionality equivalent to a hardware network switch.  Each of the `tap` interfaces is automatically created by QEMU for each virtual machine I run (I've only listed two such interfaces here, but I regularly have at least a dozen) when I use the `-net bridge` option for QEMU, and acts like the cable connecting the (virtual) NIC in the VM to the bridge interface.  In this particular case, I actually don't have any physical hardware connected to this bridge interface (so it's what's sometimes called a 'floating' or 'virtual' bridge), and instead use routing rules on the host system to provide external network access for the virtual machines.  If I wanted to isolate a couple VM's from the rest, I could easily create a new bridge interface, and tell QEMU to hook them up to that instead of `br0`.

In your case, based on the tags for the question, you appear to want to use VirtualBox, which has similar functionality to this with it's 'Internal Network' and 'Host-only' adapters.  The first one works just like the bridge setup I talked about above, except VirtualBox itself provides the bridge instead of the OS doing so, and it provides the option of acting as a DHCP server.  The second one is literally a point-to-point link between the VM and the Host system.  it's not very useful for low-level configuration experiments, but is wonderfully useful for experimenting with VPN's (because the link only goes to the host, you can be certain that any two VM's are only talking over a VPN link).

Now, while all this will work just fine for experimenting with networking configuration, it isn't exactly the most efficient option.  Depending on the exact specifics of the type of experimentation you want to do, you may find that either [Open vSwitch](http://openvswitch.org/) or [ns-3](https://www.nsnam.org/) are a better fit for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox will do that nicely.  You'll want to use "host only" network type or "internal only".

Host only - creates a virtual NIC on your machine, attaches it to a virtual switch that the VM(s) attach to as well.  You can have multiples on different subnets, etc.

Internal only - creates a virtual switch that the VM(s) connect to.  No connection to your host.  You can create multiple, and they aren't connected to each other, can be same subnet or different subnets.

What I would recommend is a VM with 2+ interfaces on it, one on a host-only network (so your desktop/laptop can connect to it) and the others on different internal-only networks.  Set the VM up as a router/bridge between your host and the internal-only network(s), create multiple machines on each internal only network.

I've done this (using a bridge interface instead of host only so my private networks could use internet) and have had 12 vms going on 3 different subnets with routing between them all and fake DNS and email and ... all set up.  Great way to learn and experiment.